# How can I get intersection of rows from table?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How can I get data in a single row?
For example I want to get intersection of rows from the example table below.

```
CODE           STATE_DATE1   STATE_DATE2  STATE_DATE3  STATE_DATE4
100_B           2023-04-10    2023-04-11   NULL         NULL
100_B           2023-04-10    2023-04-11   NULL         2023-04-12
100_B           2023-04-10    2023-04-11   2023-04-12   NULL
```

Expected result:

```
CODE      STATE_DATE1   STATE_DATE2  STATE_DATE3  STATE_DATE4
100_B      2023-04-10    2023-04-11   2023-04-12   2023-04-12
```

Comment: Also _specify_ the expected result, i.e. a [mcve].

Comment: You need to provide the rules to accumulate two rows into one. Then translate them into SQL statement. Otherwise it's impossible. For example, you didn't say what if , for example, `state_date1` is different for all the rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `group by` and `min` or `max` aggregation function:

```sql
SELECT
    CODE,
    MAX(STATE_DATE1) STATE_DATE1,
    MAX(STATE_DATE2) STATE_DATE2,
    MAX(STATE_DATE3) STATE_DATE3,
    MAX(STATE_DATE4) STATE_DATE4
FROM
    MYTABLE
GROUP BY
    CODE
```